# Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kf.a

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I am using `Googlemap` activity on my App. `minSdkVersio 15` and `tagetSdkVersion 21`. I am getting following exception for the device api **below 16** and my code works perfectly fine for **api 16 and above.** How to get over with this?
It says `Nullpointerexception` for actionbar search. I am using `appcompat v7`.

```
08-08 12:37:17.359: E/dalvikvm(32201): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kf.a
08-08 12:37:17.379: E/dalvikvm(32201): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.kf.b
08-08 12:37:17.900: E/dalvikvm(32201): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.jy.a
```

Answer (score 0):

The classes displayed in the error are only available since API 16, and you should use the equivalent from the support libraries. e.g., [android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigTextStyle.html) was introduced in api 16, you need to use [android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle.html), the equivalent class from the support library, if you want it to work on devices with api < 16.

If this is in your code, you must change the includes and probably some code. If it's in google map, then you should probably use [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) instead of the regular one.

Answer (score -1):

Please include latest version of android support library. Use SDK manager to download the latest version of Android Support Library and then follow the steps for Adding libraries with resources- https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html and add the library to your application project.