# Google Fit API Distance - Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzb

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm building a fitness app using Google Fit API and I can't get the distance that the user walked, giving me the title's error on a API 17 device (only one that I tested).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from) is similar but didn't solved my problem and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890700/could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from-method-com-goo) maybe is the same situation as mine.

Is the DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA not available on API 17? I can't test in another device because I don't have another device with me and the only emulator that I know that can use Google Play Services is the Android Studio's emulator and I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[AppOpsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager.html) was added in API Level 19, so you can maybe try to modify your manifest to a higher version. Just check the APIs you're using and make sure they're compatible to the version you're going to use.

In regards to the [DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/data/DataType.html#fields), I don't think it's the one causing this issue.

Comment: But I can get the steps and calories from Google Fit, but I can't get the distance...